# Can't acces TextView defined in onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am still a Java beginner and I have the problem that I have a onClick function and of course the onCreate in which i define the TextView to a value. But when I want to edit the TextView from the onClick i can't do that. Now I would like to know how I can make the TextView value "global".

```
final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate the `TextView` after the `setcontentView()` method :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `TextView` above method `onCreate`.

```
 TextView result;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your class you create an attribute:

```
private Textview tv;
```

then in onCreate method you initialise this variable like this :

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
```

Then you can use it wherever you want in your class by calling "tv".

Comment: It's incomplete regarding the placement of the second code row

Comment: Ofc not, he is asking how he can access the Textview anywhere in the code, that's exactly how he should proccess.